# how to style php file with css + 1 more than one element

Tags: php, html, css

Im trying to style a php file with a linked stylesheet however not having heaps of luck. I currently have the  in the body to change the font however I also wanted to add a border and maybe other things but they all use the similar commands so i can only use 1 otherwise closing of the tag

will close off either either style element.

How does one use multiple element styles in page? Is it possible to be able to color the time stamp differently from the text color? I cant seem to get my head around it.

The below file is data being pulled from a database where a game server is sending the in game chat to and then im viewing it on the web browser. I want to implement this somehow into my site/forum probably as an iframe.

Can anyone offer me any advice?

*link to live chat -->* [index.php](http://fragthugs.com/rustwebchat/index.php)

**Index.php**

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10";>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css' />
<style>
p.solid {border-style:solid;}
p {font-size:15px;}
p.sansserif{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="sansserif">

<?php
// Database config
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', '****');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '****');
define('DB_NAME', '****');
// --
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOSTNAME.'; dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$qry = $db->query("SELECT timestamp, name, message FROM webchat ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

  echo "[".date('H:i:s', $row['timestamp'])."]".htmlspecialchars($row['name']).": ".htmlspecialchars($row['message'])."<br>";
}
$db = null;
?>
</p> 

</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any assistance :)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I can't understand your need

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can edit the color by this code:-

```
    echo '<font style="color:what you want;">';
    echo "[";
echo date('H:i:s', $row['timestamp']);
    echo "]";
echo '</font>';

echo '<font style="color:what you want;">';

echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']);

echo '</font>';
echo ": ";
echo '<font style="color:what you want;">';
echo htmlspecialchars($row['message']);
echo "<br>";
echo '</font>';
```

Comment: there was an answer previously which for some reason is gone now but it said to use this

echo '<font style="color:#7e0004;">'."[".date('H:i:s', $row['timestamp'])."]".'</font>'.htmlspecialchars($row['name']).":".htmlspecialchars($row['message'])."<br>";


that worked however i still cant get to work if i wanted to change the color of the name field to something else either?

Comment: Yes i had an error in the previous code. i defined the font style and the variable in the same echo. they are to be done in different echos in this one. ex:-

echo '<font style="color:red;">'.$p.'</font>; is wrong but

echo '<font style="color:red;">';
echo $p;
echo '</font>' 
is correct

Comment: even for the name field try doing like this:-

echo '<font style="color:what you want;">'."[";
echo date('H:i:s', $row['timestamp']);
echo '</font>';

I hope the above answer that i gave works
echo "]".'</font>';

echo '<font style="color:what you want;">';
echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']).": ";

Comment: did u use the right code then? I thought u were showing me the echo code for name change but that appears to be for timestamp again? --I just keep getting errors anytime i try to do it - still unsure of where the formatting has to begin and end

Comment: you just have do one thing, echo everything in different lines.

The formatting is that..

echo '<font style="color:your color;"';
Now you define every variable that you want to format like

echo htmlspecialchars($row['name']); echo $any-variable;

And after you have echoed all the variables. close the font tag. like this

echo '</font>';

For this particular problem of yours am posting a comment. copy that and see if it works.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Copy the code and paste it and it should work. Use the color codes that you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can style multiple elements by separating them with `,`

```
body, a {
   color:#000;
}
```

You can wrap the timestamps with some tag and style that tag in css